# Mysql exception"out of range"?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I am working in swing based project and use prepared statement but it give exception like out of range and when i using parameters and do not put '?' but simply ? then show exception like"
jdbc syntax error check the manual near '?,?' at line one " i am so confused what is happening.Check my code what is wrong?

```
private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (((JTextField) chose.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText() == null) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO expance1 ( Breakfast,Date) VALUES (?,?)";
    } else {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO expance1 ( Breakfast,Date) VALUES (?,?)";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, breakfast.getText());
            pst.setString(2, ((JTextField) chose.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            pst.executeUpdate(sql);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert sucessfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add that exception please. And I mean whole stack trace ofc.

Comment: jdbc4.mysqlSyntaxErroException:you have an error in your SQL Syntaxt.check the manual that correspond to your MySql server version for the right syntaxt to use near "?,?)' at line 1

Comment: Here are some advices you should check before we can help you:
1. Are the names correct (column name and table name)?
2. Are the colum types correct (both must be VARCHAR or similar types)?
3. Is the returning string of you both methods in the .setString() statement that what you want to save?

Comment: No Breakfast is int data type while date is VARCHAR while column name and table name are correct.

Comment: Now i change int to VARCHAR but still same exception.

Comment: try to delete the space at in the bracets "INSERT INTO expance1 ( Bre..." and put a semicolon at the end of the statemend after "... VALUES (?,?);". does this help?

Comment: if you have any idea please share thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
 pst.executeUpdate(sql);
```

by

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

The SQL query has already been passed to the statement when preparing it. You must not pass it a second time. Passing it executes the literal SQL query, not the prepared one.

Comment: A JDBC driver must throw an exception when an `executeXXX(String)` method is called on a `PreparedStatement`. It is a bug in MySQL that it even tries to actually execute it (which then results in a syntax error).